# Function to parse jQuery elements contains brackets

Tags: javascript, nested, brackets

I have this text

```
( ) ( ( ) ( ( ) ) ( ( ) ) )
```

Pratically each bracket is a span and i have writed this code to organize the nested structure:

```
myobj.each(function(i) { 

    var isOpen = $( this ).text( ) == '(' ? true: false;

    if( isOpen ) {
        console.log( ' open at: ' + index  )
        index++;
        closer = index;
    } else {
       closer--;
       console.log( 'close at: ' + ( closer ) );
    }

});
```

Assuming that the expeted output would be:

```
0 0 1 2 2 3 4 4 3 5 6 6 5 1
( ) ( ( ) ( ( ) ) ( ( ) ) )
```

it give me:

```
0 0 1 2 2 3 4 4 3 5 6 6 5 4
( ) ( ( ) ( ( ) ) ( ( ) ) )
```

note the last bracket.. Why?

Comment: you are only decreasing it by one each type, how are you expecting it to go from 5 to 1? 
You're keeping the number of brackets not the bracket origin, consider using a stack data structure

Comment: yes, i know, but i must know ho i can perform this instruction first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the unclosed (just opened) bracket's index in an array, then use [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last unclosed one when closing.

```
var index = -1, unclosed = [], log = [];
myobj.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === '(') {
        index++;
        console.log('Open at: ' + index);
        unclosed.push(index);
        log.push(index);
    } else {
        var closer = unclosed.pop();
        console.log('Closed at: ' + closer);
        log.push(closer);
    }
});
console.log(log); //[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 6, 5, 1]
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C2GkL/2/)

The `log` above is just for showing the final result, those 3 lines + declaration can later be removed.

Comment: Thank @Fabrício Matté for your answer, but it is not what i search..
The index that you store in log is pratically a set of span elements.. I would assign it an hover element: for example if over on 1 the relative 1 should be highlighted.
The points in this way is that i cant store these elements in an array like [[0,0],[1,1].....]. How i can do it? Thanks

Comment: @koMah Glad my algorithm helped, also you can use an object instead of an array of arrays to make the code slightly simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/C2GkL/8/ I've also added the hover effect to the closing brackets.

Comment: It is also possible to do without indexes and without extra iterations: http://jsfiddle.net/C2GkL/9/